# Why am I not able to see the local variables used at a debug point in angularJS library JS file

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to see the value of a variable inside a function when the execution is paused at a debug point inside the function using chrome's developer tools .I selected/hovered over the variable but the tooltip with the value is not appearing unlike normal javascript function in other js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try type the variable name in console window, you should be able to see what is the variable value.

example :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the whole variable name and hover it again.